# I want to return a decoded value as output from subdirectory that has encoded data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

```
C:\Desktop\folder\funcs.js:88
  return "from" + decode(inbox.messages[found].from) + "\n---\n" + ^
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
>       at Object.module.exports.findNextMessage (C:\Desktop\folder\funcs

According to a lot of forums, reinstalling/upgrading and downgrading of versions helped but nothing worked for me. The same error occurs for .hash.

```
    return "from" + decode(inbox.messages[found].from) + "\n---\n" +
decode(fs.readFile(path.join(inbox.dir, inbox.messages[found].hash), "utf8"))
```